# Split string by comma, space and quetes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to split a string by comma, space and quetes. for example:

Input:

```
"Super Bus" dri"ver bus1, driver1
```

output:

```
"Super Bus"
dri"ver
bus1
driver1
```

This is my regex(it splits by space and comme):

```
Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("[ ,]+")
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Comment: I'm using vb.net.. thanks

Comment: what's your expected output if the input is `"Super Bus" dri"ver bus1, dri"ver1` ?

Comment: 1) "Super Bus"
2) Dri"ver
3) bus1
4) Dri"ver1

Comment: why `"ver bus1 Dri"` isn't calculated as a single word? is that the double quoted string is always surrounded by boundaries?

Comment: It's a good question! I need to think about that.. thank you!

Comment: Couse the questes are found in the middle of the word..

Comment: i think there is no non-word character present in your string other than quotes, comma and space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to do matching instead of splitting.

```
[^,\s]*\b"\b[^,\s]*|"[^"]*"|[^,\s]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rO3kJ1/1)